# calling variable generated from another php file without include or require

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm extremely newbie for php & Wordpress that just started learning php by my own. I read through many answers but couldn't solve my problem, so I decided to post it here.

I have 2 page templates for WP, Page A & B, A.php is parent of B.php.
I have a **checkbox** in B.php to determine whether this is the latest page or not.

```
if( get_field('this_months_issue') )
{
    echo "<span class=\"issue-status\">/&nbsp;This Month's Issue</span>";
    $latest = "is-latest";  
}
else
{
    echo "<span class=\"issue-status\">/&nbsp;Previous Issue</span>";
}
```

I want Page A to be landed on the latest Page B when the checkbox is checked. (Please note that Page B can be use for many other child-page under Page A)

What can I put in Page A so that it can redirect to the Page that have the checkbox checked?

Sorry for my poor english, I hope you can understand my question.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your variable in a session.
so call `session_start();` at the top off the pages

```
        //set
        $_SESSION['varname'] = "something";
        // retrieve
        $somevar = $_SESSION['varname'];
        echo $somevar;//will echo "something";
```

so whenever that session is active, you can call it anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you for answering..</br>
Do i apply  
`//set  
$_SESSION['varname'] = "something";` in Page B;   
and  
`// retrieve  
$somevar = $_SESSION['varname'];  
echo $somevar;//will echo "something";` in Page A?

Comment: use `$_SESSION['varname'] = "something";` on the page where you declare your variables and then use `$somevar = $_SESSION['varname'];` where you want to do stuff with it.